# MySQL : on creating foreign key geting error no : 150

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

the table ENUMSTATE refrying  ENUMCOUNTRY but

This code results in this error: Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'easylibdb1.enumstate' (errno: 150)

=> Enum Country

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENUMCOUNTRY(

    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',
    SHORTNAME VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',
    STATUS BIT DEFAULT FALSE,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

=> Enum STATE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENUMSTATE(

    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',
    SHORTNAME VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',
    STATUS BIT DEFAULT FALSE,
    COUNTRYID INT,      
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    FOREIGN KEY (COUNTRYID) REFERENCES ENUMCOUNTRY(ID)  
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're 2 mistakes in the `ENUMSTATE`

1. You are missing comma after `PRIMARY KEY (ID)`

   ```
   PRIMARY KEY (ID),
   ```
2. The Foreign key must have the same definition defined in a reference table (*Primary key in reference table*) with the same data type and the size.

   ```
   COUNTRYID INT UNSIGNED
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Change table definition for `ENUMSTATE` with

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENUMSTATE(

    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',
    SHORTNAME VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',
    STATUS BIT DEFAULT FALSE,
    COUNTRYID INT UNSIGNED,   -- < type should be UNSIGNED as PK in ENUMCOUNTRY  
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),  -- < you're missing comma here
    FOREIGN KEY (COUNTRYID) REFERENCES ENUMCOUNTRY(ID)  
);
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb6d7)** demo

> **[Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)**
>   **Corresponding columns in the foreign key
>   and the referenced key must have similar data types. The size and sign
>   of integer types must be the same.** The length of string types need not
>   be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character
>   set and collation must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma after `PRIMARY KEY (ID)` in your ENUMSTATE table

Answer (score 0):

There is no comma after `PRIMARY KEY (ID)` in ENUMSTATE table. That is the reason you are getting syntax error.